# Regroup returning a None type grouper when it shouldn't

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to use the regroup template tag to order a list of blog post publish dates by the year they were published.

The queryset I am passing into my context to be regrouped is:

```
 'post_archive_months': Post.objects.published().\
 filter(site__id=settings.SITE_ID).dates('publish','month').reverse(),
```

In the template, I call it as such:

```
<section class="blog_archive_block">
  <h4>Blog Archive</h4>
    {% regroup post_archive_months by year as post_archive_dates %}
    <ul class="" id="">
      {% for year in post_archive_dates %}
      <li>
        <div class="header_box">
          <h4>{{year.grouper}} <a href="#" class="arrow_up"></a></h4>
        </div>
        <div class="content_box">
          <ul class="month">
          {% for month in year.list %}
            <li>
              <a href="/blog/{{year.grouper}}/{{month|date:'M'}}">{{month|date:"F"}}</a>
            </li>
          {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</section>
```

The data returned is:

```
[{'list': [[datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2012, 5,    
1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 
datetime.datetime(2011, 10, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), datetime.datetime(2011, 8, 1, 0, 0,   
tzinfo=<UTC>)]], 'grouper': None}]
```

I would have expected the grouper to be a year, or at least something besides a None type, but this does not seem to be the case.

Let me know if you need more information from me.  Thanks!